# Sending a range to a custom function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a custom function in google datasheet. I call the function this way:

`=foo(A1:A3)`

The function is declared as:

```
function foo(input) {
    return input.length
}
```

And it returns 1. What is wrong? What I have to do to return the length of the `input` range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments):

> If you call your function with a reference to a range of cells as an argument (like `=DOUBLE(A1:B10)`), the argument will be a two-dimensional array of the cells' values. For example, in the screenshot below, the arguments in `=DOUBLE(A1:B2)` are interpreted by Apps Script as `double([[1,3],[2,4]])`.
>
> [image: Picture from Google Documentation]

So you're seeing `1` because there's only one row in your range. To see how many cells are in that row:

```
function foo(input) {
    return input[0].length;
}
```

...which should give you `3`, because the array passed to your function should look like this:

```
[valueOfA1, valueOfA2, valueOfA3]
```

I don't know if empty ranges are possible in Google Spreadsheets, but if they are, you might want to add a guard:

```
function foo(input) {
    return input && input[0] && input[0].length;
}
```

Comment: Ah!!! Thank you very much... It was a esily question but I read the document you show and didn't understand it properly.

Comment: @JuanPabloCabreraBorges: ¡De nada! :-)